# Global Object and assignment - why does it recognize the assignment?

Tags: javascript

When I run in the console, I don't quite follow why it yields a result of zero. I thought both MyObject and myFunc are global. What concept am I missing to understand this properly?

```
myObject = {
length: 400,
};

function myFunc () {
return console.log(this.length);

}

myFunc(myObject.length); // equals zero
```

Comment: `this` refers to the `window` object which should have length 1.

Comment: @megawac why should it have a length of 1? [MDN: Window.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.length)

Comment: @megawac - Stack seems to set the length to 1 for whatever reason, it is defaulted at 0.

Comment: @TravisJ: It's the number of frames/iframes in the document. So for many (most?) documents, it would be `0`, but of course if you have one frame/iframe, it'll be `1`; two, it'll be `2`, and so on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Ah, and there are frames for the ads.

Comment: @TravisJ: Yup. And amusingly, for me, it's `0`. So I guess the Careers 2.0 ad I'm seeing over there on the right isn't in a frame/iframe. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's showing you the value of `window.length` (which is the number of frames/iframes in the document). To have `myFunc` show you the value of the `length` of the object you pass into it, you'd have to use that argument:

```
function myFunc (obj) {
    return console.log(obj.length);
}
```

If you're trying to explore [implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (your `myObject` is an implicit global; they're a Bad Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>), then `myFunc` should be called with no arguments and should use `myObject.length` or possibly `this.myObject.length` (which come to the same thing).

Comment: What I don't get is when I type "window.myObject.length" on the console it does recognize 400.  This is where I get confused. Doesn't that mean that myObject is global? If yes, why isn't the function realizing this?

Comment: @Iditarod1973: Yes, you're quite right, `myObject` is a global. But you're not using that global in `myFunc`. You're trying to use `length`, not `myObject.length`. And so you're getting the value of a *different* global, `length`, which is unrelated to `myObject.length`. `myObject.length` is not a global, it's a *property* of an object that is referenced from the global `myObject`.

Comment: Crowder: Thanks! Let me run it by you one more time to make sure I got it.  myObject as a global is really "window.myObject" so when I'm using "this.length" on "myFunc", it looks for "window.length" and not "window.myObject.length".  Is that the correct thought process?

Comment: @Iditarod1973: Perfect. And the reason `myFunc` is doing that is down to the way you're calling it. More: [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) and [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the object as a parameter, but you're not receiving it in the function. `this` in the context of `myFunc` is not the object `myObject`. It is the `window` object.

To achieve what you're trying to do, modify your code like so:

```
myObject = {
    length: 400,
};

function myFunc (obj) {
    return console.log(obj.length); 
}

myFunc(myObject); // equals zero
```

**Note:**

To verify that `this` is the `window` object, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/rhrt9/) where I've modified your console line to be `return console.log(this);`. The console outputs the `Window` object.

[**Demonstration Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/rhrt9/1/)